# Customize SqlDataSource to store part of string

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, webforms

I'm using an UpdatePanel in ASP.Net WebForms to upload a image. I set the `Image.ImageUrl` to the full virtual path to the image (`/images/news/filenname.jpg`), but I only want to save the filename in the database (`filename.jpg`). How do I customize the `SqlDataSource` to only take part of the URL?

```
<asp:SqlDataSource 
  ID="SqlDataSourceNews" 
  runat="server" 
  ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:connectionString %>" 
  UpdateCommand="UPDATE [foo] SET [pic] = @pic WHERE [id] = @id">
   <UpdateParameters>
      <asp:Parameter Name="pic" Type="String" />
   </UpdateParameters>
   <InsertParameters>
      <asp:Parameter Name="pic" Type="String" />
    </InsertParameters>
 </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the update parameters on page_load and use substring function to get only file name from full url:

```
protected void Buton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        SqlDataSource1.UpdateParameters["pic"].DefaultValue = "string fetched from substring method";
        SqlDataSource1.Update();
}
```